# Why PowerShell consider @() syntax differently

Tags: powershell

Array initialization works differently in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)

```
$scripts = @(
    ("01", "a" , "01_Cleanup")
    ,("02", "b" , "02_Cleanup")
);
```

**Output:**

```
$scripts[0] - "01"
$scripts[1] - "a"
$scripts[2] - "01_Cleanup"
$scripts[3] - "02"
"b"
"02_Cleanup"
```

---

Please notice "," in array initialization.:

```
$scripts = @(
    ("01", "a" , "01_Cleanup"),
    ("02", "b" , "02_Cleanup")
);
```

**Output:**

```
$scripts[0] - "01"
"a"
"01_Cleanup"
$scripts[1] - "02"
"b"
"02_Cleanup"
```

Why?

Comment: you've pasted the wrong output for the cases ;) anyway, i think this is because of the fact that there's no indication to continue on the next line. so it treats first array as separate elements. but I would also be interested in a more concise answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its because of different usage of the [Comma operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) (**binary** vs **unary**):

> As a binary operator, the comma creates an array. As a unary operator,
>   the comma creates an array with one member. Place the comma before the
>   member.

---

**Binary:**

```
@(
    ("01", "a" , "01_Cleanup"),
    ("02", "b" , "02_Cleanup")
) | foreach { Write-Host $_};
```

Output:

```
01 a 01_Cleanup
02 b 02_Cleanup
```

---

**Unary:**

```
 @(
    ("01", "a" , "01_Cleanup")
    ,("02", "b" , "02_Cleanup")
) | foreach { Write-Host $_};
```

Output:

```
01
a
01_Cleanup
02 b 02_Cleanup
```

Comment: but why does it treat first array as separate elements in the second case?

Comment: The answer covers your question. "As a unary operator, the comma creates an array with one member"

Comment: well, i guess my question was more like why does this $a = @(('a','b')) is treated like 2 separate elements. I can create a question for that if you would like

Comment: It's counterintuitive to say the least but the solution would be to explicitly add the unary operator like `$a=@(,('a','b'))`.